# materializecss selectbox: option not selectable

Tags: jquery, html, css, materialize

### The Problem

I have a selectbox from materialize in a container with `position:absolute`.
Right under this container there is another container with something in it (also `position:absolute`). The containers have the same `z-index`.

When I want to select something in the selectbox, the option which overlaps the secound container is not clickable. :(

### What I tried

I tried to set the `z-index` to a higher value if the selectbox is focused like that:

```
$(".select-dropdown").on("focusin",function(){
    $(this).parents(".content-container").css("zIndex","100");
});
```

Also I tried to make the containers positioned relative, which worked, but unfortunatelly I cant do that in the final solution.

### [The jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3typfz1z/)

**How to make all options of the selectbox clickable, if it is in an absolute positioned container?**

*Note: Here I am reasking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46927922/5147965), but a little bit simpler, since I was able to remove the gridstack part and narrowed it down to the materialize selectbox.*

Comment: Try the second dropdown --> http://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/tqkadcq0/ -- I've added `pointer-events: none` to `div.three`. Is this suitable?

Comment: Sadly not. There could be a input field in the other container. http://jsfiddle.net/tqkadcq0/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is so easy, you just have to remove `z-index: 80` under `.content-container, .card` because both `div` have the same class `.content-container` which mean the same `z-index` and this was making a wrong behavior.
Also without the need of Javascript.

Check the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3typfz1z/1/) , hope this helps.

**Update**

Just add `z-index` for `div.one` to prevent input or other elements to override the dropdown list.

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tqkadcq0/3/) with input below dropdwon list.